# Is box sizing inherited if declared inside universal selector?

Tags: css, reset

Does this get applied by every element?

EXAMPLE 'A':

```
*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I thought box-sizing is not inherited?

This is in regards to box sizing reset:

EXAMPLE 'B':

```
*, *::before, *::after
{
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Will both examples have the same effect?

Comment: If you have a rule somewhere that will do `.some-class { box-sizing: content-box; }`, then in the first case, children of elements that have the class `.some-class` will still have their own `box-sizing` set to `border-box`, while in the second case, they will inherit the `content-box` one.

Comment: no, the example B means every element and pseudo-element is set to box-sizing: border-box.

Comment: No, it means every elements and pseudo-elements are set to `box-sizing: inherit`. So they will inherit it from their parent. https://jsfiddle.net/kL0f75pr/

Answer (score 6):

> I thought box-sizing is not inherited?

No, it's not. You can check [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#box-sizing) and you will see that inherited is NO. In the example A, you are simply using the universal selector to select all the elements and applying `box-sizing:border-box` to them but it doesn't target pseudo element so they will not have `box-sizing:border-box` set by default.

> Will both examples have the same effect?

No they won't. Even if we consider that it's the only CSS applied to your document, the example B will also target pseudo element to make them inherit the `box-sizing` and if we follow the parent-child structure they will logically get `box-sizing:border-box` since `html` is having `box-sizing:border-box`.

The other difference is that using `inherit` will consider the parent style unlike explicitly setting the value in the example A. In the example A, you have to change `box-sizing` for each element if you want to override the one set by your code while in the example B, changing `box-sizing` on the element OR any ancestor will override the code you are using.

---

A basic example to illustrate the difference.

Using A:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



/* my code*/
body {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:10px solid;
  padding:10px;
}

p {
  padding:5px;
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Using B:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* my code*/

body {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 10px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

p {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: In example B you have set html to be border-box and body to be content-box so parent-child inheritance based upon the wildcard `box-sizing: inherit` results in content-box not border-box as you stated. The structure is html > body > content

Comment: @Bradley I was refering to the example B of the question. The last example of my answer comes after the explanation and I said nothing about it. The result should be based on the explanation above

Comment: Fair enough, might want to make it less ambiguous as if I was mistaken by it others might be too. That being said, the content helped me understand it better so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. To confirm with a test:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.example {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.border-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-box {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="example"></div>
  <div class="example content-box"></div>
  <div class="example border-box"></div>
<body>
```

The `div` that does not have the `.border-box` class still inherits its `box-sizing` from `body`.

Comment: then what's the point of doing box sizing reset as in example B above? https://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/

Comment: universal selector works because it has nothing to  do with inheritance in itself. it just points to 'any' element. so it's like a static setting for every element.