# Which variant is more suitable to specify box-sizing for the whole document?

Tags: css

Sometimes I see this kind of code in the very beginning of the document:

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

**I don't understand the purpose of :before and :after pseudo-elements in it.** Why isn't the

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

just enough?

**Thanks :)**

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/59495417/8620333 (cannot close since there is no upvote)

Answer (score 3):

You can read a very good explanations [here](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/#article-header-id-3). It explains perfectly your doubt.

> **The "Old" *border-box* Reset** 
> The earliest `box-sizing: border-box;` reset
>   looked like this:
>
> `* {
>     box-sizing: border-box;
>   }`
>  
>   This works fairly well, but it leaves out pseudo elements, which can lead to some unexpected results. A
>   revised reset that covers pseudo elements quickly emerged:
>
> **Universal Box Sizing**
>   `*, *:before, *:after {
>      box-sizing: border-box;
>   }` 
>   This method selected pseudo elements as well, improving the normalizing effect of
>   `border-box`. But, the `*` selector makes it difficult for developers to
>   use `content-box` or `padding-box` elsewhere in the CSS. Which brings us
>   to the current frontrunner for best practice:
>
> **Universal Box Sizing with Inheritance** 
>   `html {
>    box-sizing: border-box;
>   }
>   *, *:before, *:after {
>    box-sizing: inherit;
>   }`
>  This reset gives you more flexibility than its predecessors — you can use `content-box` or
>   `padding-box` (where supported) at will, without worrying about a
>   universal selector overriding your CSS. We went into more depth on
>   this technique and the reasoning behind it in "Inheriting box-sizing
>   Probably Slightly Better Best Practice". One potential gripe with it
>   is that `box-sizing` isn't normally inherited, so it's specialized
>   behavior, not quite the same as something you'd normally put in a
>   reset.

Other sources:

- https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp,
- https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_box-sizing3,
- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp

Comment: The section you quoted isn't the relevant bit... the good stuff is in here https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/#article-header-id-3 you might want to quote the interesting bits instead.

Comment: Yes, I realized it